# How to list interface methods omitting property accessors

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, properties, interface

I would like to use reflection to display a list of methods in an interface.

```
public interface IRoadVehicle
{
  int WheelCount { get; }
  bool IsEmergency();
}
```

I use following code:

```
foreach (var m in typeof(IRoadVehicle).GetMethods())
{
  Console.WriteLine(m.Name);
}
```

However, I also get listed the compiler-generated property accessors if the interface has a property. I would like to differentiate between explicitly-defined methods and property accessors to omit the latter.

```
//output:
//get_WheelCount
//IsEmergency

//desired output:
//IsEmergency
```

How can I filter out the property-related methods?

Comment: Filtering methods which start by get_ or set_ is not enough for you?

Comment: @BlueM someone could do something silly like name a real method `get_Thing()`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the [`IsSpecialName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.isspecialname.aspx) property:

```cs
foreach (var m in typeof(IRoadVehicle).GetMethods().Where(x => !x.IsSpecialName))
{
    // ...
}
```

This removes all methods with a name that is treated somehow special by the compiler. The docs say this about it:

> The SpecialName bit is set to flag members that are treated in a special way by some compilers (such as property accessors and operator overloading methods).

Comment: That is a pretty handy property to know about.

Comment: Nice. IsSpecialName is something good to know!

Answer (score 9):

How about:

```
var type = typeof(IRoadVehicle);

var accessors = type.GetProperties().SelectMany(property => property.GetAccessors());
var methods = type.GetMethods()
                  .Except(accessors);
```

You can also use `IsSpecialName` like Daniel Hilgarth mentions, but note that this will also exclude other "special" methods like operators (not an issue for interfaces) and event-accessors. Depends on what you want, really.

Comment: Much tidier than `IsSpecialName`.